# Difference between junit-jupiter-api and junit-jupiter-engine

Tags: java, junit, junit5

What's the difference between maven modules `junit-jupiter-api` and `junit-jupiter-engine`? Is it necessary to include both dependencies in `build.gradle`?

Do I need to provide both dependencies?

```
testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
```

Or only one dependency is enough?

```
testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
```

And do I need to add a dependency on `junit-vintage-engine`?

Comment: Minor improvement: The recommendation of the JUnit team is to use `testRuntime` for both engines.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

#### JUnit Prior to Version 5.4

From [the docs](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview-what-is-junit-5):

> **`junit-jupiter-api`**
>
> JUnit Jupiter API for writing tests and extensions.
>
> **`junit-jupiter-engine`**
>
> JUnit Jupiter test engine implementation, only required at runtime.
>
> **`junit-vintage-engine`**
>
> JUnit Vintage test engine implementation that allows to run vintage JUnit tests, i.e. tests written in the JUnit 3 or JUnit 4 style, on the new JUnit Platform.

So ...

- You need both `junit-jupiter-api` and `junit-jupiter-engine` to write and run JUnit5 tests
- You only need `junit-vintage-engine` if (a) you are running with JUnit5 **and** (b) your test cases use JUnit4 constructs/annotations/rules etc

#### JUnit from Version 5.4 Onwards

In JUnit 5.4 this is simplified, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55084036/8200937) for more details.

Comment: You don't need to add both as `jupiter-api` is a transitive dependency of `jupiter-engine`.

Comment: In 5.5.1 version, I am able to write and run junit tests with the "junit-jupiter-api" only.

Comment: @gaurav, yes, that's covered in this part of my answer _Note: in JUnit 5.4 this is simplified, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55084036/8200937) for more details._

Comment: @glytching, but @Gaurav (and I) is using `junit-jupiter-api` only, not `junit-jupiter`

Answer (score 80):

## `junit-jupiter` aggregator artifact

[JUnit 5.4 provides](https://hub.packtpub.com/junit-5-4-released-with-an-aggregate-artifact-for-reducing-your-maven-and-gradle-files/) much simpler Maven configuration if your intent is to write JUnit 5 tests. Simply specify the aggregate artifact named [`junit-jupiter`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter).

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

As an aggregate, this artifact in turn pulls the following three artifacts automatically, for your convenience:

- [`junit-jupiter-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api) (a compile dependency)
- [`junit-jupiter-params`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-params)  (a compile dependency)
- [`junit-jupiter-engine`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine)  (a runtime dependency)

In your project, you will also end up with:

- junit-platform-commons-1.4.0.jar
- junit-platform-engine-1.4.0.jar

The above is what you need to **write and run JUnit 5 tests** based on the new Jupiter paradigm.

## Legacy tests

If your project has JUnit 3 or 4 tests that you want to continue to run, add another dependency for the *JUnit Vintage Engine*, [`junit-vintage-engine`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.vintage/junit-vintage-engine). See [tutorial by IBM](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/j-introducing-junit5-part2-vintage-jupiter-extension-model/).

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.vintage/junit-vintage-engine -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is the best answer, in my opinion.

Comment: According to the official samples (https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview-getting-started-example-projects) I suggest to handle the versions in the JUnit BOM (Bill Of Material): "org.junit:junit-bom"

Answer (score 14):

Just to note, `junit-jupiter-api` is included as a sub-dependency in `junit-jupiter-engine` Maven repository. So you'll only really need to add `junit-jupiter-engine` to get both. I'm sure gradle is the same.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine/5.1.1

Comment: Now simplified in JUnit 5.4 and later to simply `<artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>`.

Answer (score 3):

The most accurate answer to your questions is in [junit-team/junit5-samples](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples) repository. Just take a look at [junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/master/junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle) for Gradle and [junit5-jupiter-starter-maven](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/master/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven) for maven.

As you can see in both examples the only required dependency is `junit-jupiter`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the tests using the Junit 5, you will only need the `junit-jupiter-api`. If you use the `junit-jupiter-engine` along with, your tests will broke and will not run.

I'm not sure why it was placed, but, the previous answer informs that you will need to use the both is incorrect.