# Unable to get JUnit4 and JUnit5 tests to run together - maven, surefire

Tags: maven, spring-boot, junit, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

**UPDATE**

This is **NOT** a duplicate question. The quoted duplicate answer is something that I had reviewed already.

The issue for me was the version of the `junit-vintage-engine` that I was using `5.4.2` did not work `5.3.2` did.

---

Currently unable to get the `maven-surefire-plugin` to run **JUnit4** tests in conjunction with **JUnit5** tests with maven.

Surefire plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*Test.java</include>
      <include>**/*Runner.java</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I add the aggregate`junit-jupiter` [(includes engine / params / api)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55084036/2440661):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

...and run `mvn test` the JUnit5 tests run but the old JUnit4 tests do not. When I remove it the JUnit4 tests run. `junit` is a provided by `spring-boot-starter-test`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I followed the instructions outlined [here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven-engines-configure) (JUnit docs), however this only resulted in the JUnit5 tests getting run. These instructions outline adding the vintage engine:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: the surefire plugin docs have a page that seems to describe what you want to do: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html

Comment: You have to add junit vintage.

Comment: @XavierBouclet Thanks, I had already added that as per the JUnit5 documentation.