# org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter

Tags: java, junit5

while migrating from junit4 to junit5, instead of

```
@Parameterized.Parameters
public static Collection input() {}
```

I have added before all the test methods

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("input")
```

but I am getting the error as :
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I think you should put your entire pom.xml and your test class in your question. I'm trying to help but wonder if your issue is reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

Example of correct implementation of parameterized test:

```java
//example with 2 parameters
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("input")
void myTest(String input, String expectedResult) {
   //test code
}

// Make sure to use the correct return type Stream<Arguments>
static Stream<Arguments> input() {
    return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of("hello", "hello"),
            Arguments.of("bye", "bye")
            //etc
    );
}
```

Also make sure you are using a compatible version of junit jupiter:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>${some.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also you need `junit-vintage-engine` dependency if you still have junit4 tests.

Comment: changed the return type of input  method as:
public static Stream<Arguments> input() {
List<TestInput> input = new ArrayList<TestInput>();
}
and made the return as: 
return Stream.of(Arguments.of(input));

In the test methods added the arguments as:
        @ParameterizedTest
 @MethodSource("input")
 public void testGetBlockNoByTxId(List<TestInput> input){}

NOT WORKING

Comment: @TanayaMitra share your pom.xml and your test class (including imports)

Comment: <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
   <version>5.7.2</version>

   <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
   <version>5.7.2</version>

@Order(1)
 @ParameterizedTest
 @MethodSource("input")
 public void testChannelServiceDiscovery2() throws Exception {}

public static Collection input() throws Exception {
  List<TestInput> input = new ArrayList<TestInput>();
  return input;
}

The same works in a different project, wondering what i am missing!

Comment: I recommend throwing out all your junit dependencies and just using `junit-jupiter` like in my example.

Also if you are using `spring-boot-starter-test` that may contain some clashing dependencies that you may have to exclude.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448331/difference-between-junit-jupiter-api-and-junit-jupiter-engine/55084036#55084036

Comment: not working...tried removing the dependencies and added only junit-jupiter

Comment: I'm using 5.6.0 maybe there's a bug in the version you are using? Also make sure to rebuild the project before rerunning the tests.